# How to initialize an array of custom type?

Tags: c#, arrays

How can I make an array with 400 elements of type `myClass` and pass different args to each of them?

I have two classes: `mainClass` and `myClass`. I want to create the array in `mainClass`. as you can see `myClass` needs 3 args.

**myClass:**

```
namespace prj1
{
    class myClass
    {
        public myClass(int A, int B int C)
        {
            ...
            ...
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

**mainClass:**

```
namespace prj1
{
    class mainClass
    {
        public myClass[] myVar = new myClass[400];

        public mainClass(int y, int m, int d)
        {
            ...
            ...
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

If I have to use `setValue` to initialize them how can I do this? How should I pass 3 args?

```
for (int i = 0; i < 400; i++)
            {
                myVar.SetValue(object Value, i);
            }
```

Comment: I dont see a public method SetValue defined in your myClass class?

Comment: @JohnGathogo: SetValue is a method of array class...

Comment: It sounds to me like you need to rethink the way you're doing things. If you need to fill an array with different objects, you're probably keeping track of them in an array or an ArrayList or something like that. If not, I've found your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
for (int i = 0; i < 400; i++)
 {
   myVar[i]=new MyClass(y,m,d);
 }
```

//or

```
for (int i = 0; i < 400; i++)
 {
   myVar.SetValue(new MyClass(y,m,d),i);
 }
```

Comment: tnx. In setValue method I missed the "new" keyword. tnx a lot.

Answer (score 5):

Why don't you just construct each instance within the loop you already have?

```
for(int i = 0; i < myVar.Length; i++)
{
    myVar[i] = new myClass(arg1, arg2, arg3);
}
```

You have an appropriate constructor already, and you're initializing within a loop... 1 + 1 == 2, let's not try and reinvent the wheel shall we?

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int i = 0; i < 400; i++)
{
    myClass tempObject = new myClass(y,m,d);
    myVar.SetValue(tempObject,i)
}
```